# Why is the solution set of the second-order differential equation, $y''+ay'+by=0$, two dimensional?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

> Why is the solution set of the second-order differential equation, $y''+ay'+by=0$, two dimensional?

All sources I have found just state that the dimensions of the solution set are two. Is the reason too obvious to state or is the proof very long? I would appreciate a proof nonetheless.

Comment: Yes... the reason is obvious.  Each integration allows a free constant.  You have a second-order equation, hence two free constants.  And so....

Comment: @DavidG.Stork What if $a=b=0?$

Comment: That is a single point in a two-dimensional space.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ S$ be the set of solutions.

consider the map from $\Bbb R^2$ to $S$ defined by

$$f(u,v)=y \text{ with }\; y(0)=u,y'(0)=v$$

$f$ is an isomorphism of vector space , thus $$\dim \; S = \dim \; \Bbb R^2=2$$